# Android AchartEngine

Tags: java, android, xml, achartengine

I need to implement a Bar chart Where it reads values when the user touches the graph to move it vertically. The graph moves up, recording the value in accordance with the axis .   With x axis being the value and the Y axis being the variables , i need to perform calculations.  Example to understand

Comment: "Touches the graph to move it vertically", u mean drag?

Comment: Yes, Drag the graph so that the value can be stored inside a variable may be for calculation,
For example well
Y axis : money.
X axis : Income and expenditure [ columns ]

The columns must be dragged to a certain height, So we could visually set it to a point where the value can be acquired from the scale.
And then , Savings = Income - Expenditure must be displayed on top.
I'm a beginner and a detailed explanation would be SO helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java) example. You can also do `mChartView.addPanListener` and handle this event for what you need.